# CouchDB DELETE a view returns 409 but GET returns no rev

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb

I'm working through the database chapter of [Node.js the Right Way](https://pragprog.com/book/jwnode/node-js-the-right-way) which uses CouchDB and interaction with JSON over REST. When creating a view I accidentally did a PUT on the wrong url:

```js
request({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://localhost:5984/books/designs/books',
  // Should have been:
  // url: 'http://localhost:5984/books/_design/books',
  json: doc
}
```

When I try to DELETE this record I get:

```
DELETE http://localhost:5984/books/designs/books

409 { error: 'conflict', reason: 'Document update conflict.' }
```

As highlighted in Node.js the Right Way

> CouchDB guards against conflicts and race conditions by demanding a revision ID for updates to an existing document. Since our request didn’t include a rev parameter at all, it didn’t match the document we were attempting to delete.
>
> So, to DELETE or PUT a document that exists, you need to provide a revision:

But a GET only returns the JSON contents of the view with no `_rev` attribute:

```
GET http://localhost:5984/books/designs/books

200 { views: 
{ by_author: 
    { map: 'function (doc) {\n      if (\'authors\' in doc) {\n        doc.authors.forEach(emit);\n      }\n    }',
        reduce: '_count' },
    by_subject: 
    { map: 'function (doc) {\n      if (\'subjects\' in doc) {\n        doc.subjects.forEach((subject) => {\n          emit(subject, subject);\n\n          subject.split(/|s+--|s+/).forEach((part) => {\n            emit(part, subject);\n          });\n        });\n      }\n    }',
        reduce: '_count' } } }
```

Even if I include ?revs_info=true it still gives the same response without the `_rev` attribute:

```
GET http://localhost:5984/books/designs/books?revs_info=true
```

Actual documents I have inserted do have `_rev` attributes and I have successfully deleted some of them. Any ideas on why this mistake doesn't appear to have a revision ID and how I could delete this record?

Comment: This may not be helped by the view having a syntax error - I was using es6 arrow functions `=>` instead of `function()`. When I fix these errors and try and reinsert them at the (wrong) URL I get `409 { error: 'conflict', reason: 'Document update conflict.' }`

Comment: Have you checked the response headers of your view? I believe the `_rev` may be encoded there too, even when the request fails.

Comment: Not in the response header either: `Accept-Ranges →none
Cache-Control →must-revalidate
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →205
Content-MD5 →NAaRXi8FdSDAINimZs4d9g==
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Mon, 27 Mar 2017 08:37:17 GMT
ETag →"NAaRXi8FdSDAINimZs4d9g=="
Server →CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/19)`

Comment: I ended up trawling through my terminal and finding the original mistaken GET which had the rev id in it. Then I can delete the record... ah well.